Inconsistent reads after a write in MySQL Aurora
I have an Aurora MySQL cluster with 1 writer and 1 reader instances. I am running a write query (like INSERT or UPDATE) and right after I receive the answer for that query, I am executing a SELECT on the writer instance and I expect to see the data, but I receive dirty data instead.
If I add a sleep inbetween the write and the read of around 1 second it will work, but I don't want to do that, otherwise I would read from the reader instance.
I am using NodeJS and mysql2 package to perform DB ops.
An example:
await db.execute("UPDATE mytable SET emotion = 'frustrated' WHERE user = 'me'")
const result = await db.execute("SELECT emotion FROM mytable WHERE user = 'me'")
// result would have the value BEFORE I updated the data - NOT 'frustrated'

What could be the reason for that?

Is the function in which you use this declared with async? await can only be used in these functions

Amazon aurora is only compatible with mysql, but is not mysql.
